# How to install the 'Quicktime'-Plugin (needed for youtube-songs in Tomahawk)?

Tags: codecs

When I want to play a song via youtube in **Tomahawk** it does not play the song. A pop-up appears and asks me to find the missing plugin which is 'Quicktime'. But there is no chance to install this plugin. As far as I know I installed every codec.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit / Tomahawk 0.3.3

When I remember correctly it worked with 11.04, but I am not really sure. But it once worked. Now I cannot play youtube-songs at all.

Comment: Have you installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras package from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Yes - that's why I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit late, but I had rather the same problem with Tomahawk version 0.5.0 under Ubuntu 12.04.

The solution is to install the **phonon-backend-vlc** package **instead of phonon-backend-gstreamer**

as they told us on the website
http://www.tomahawk-player.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

- Open Firefox.
- Load the page normally.
- Click in the Firefox menu on Tools.
- Go to Page Info.
- Click on the Tab Media.
- Scroll till you find the URI with the quicktime video (usually `.mov`).
- Copy and paste the URI/URL hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will play in the browser. If you want to download it than after this you can go to the Firefox menu click on `File`, then on `Save Page As...`

As it already will give the quicktime video extension, all you need to do is put in the folder you want to download it to.
(Works under Ubuntu 12.04, after embedded quicktime vids, that worked b4, does no longer.)